# How to add a character "\t" into a string before the newline character "\n"

Tags: c, newline, fgets, strcat

I am wondering how to take a line of string and add a tab character before the new line character. Right now I'm using fgets to get the line then using

```
strcat(line_data, "\t");
```

but that just adds the tab after the newline character

Comment: Does the string `line_data` already have a newline character at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `line_data` has enough memory:

```
char* newline = strchr(line_data, '\n');
newline[0] = '\t';
newline[1] = '\n';
newline[2] = '\0';
```

Of course, if it doesn't, you have to do something like this:

```
size_t len = strlen(line_data);
char* newstr = malloc(len + 2); /* one for '\t', another for '\0' */
memcpy(newstr, line_data, len);
newstr[len - 1] = '\t'; /* assuming '\n' is at the very end of the string */
newstr[len] = '\n';
newstr[len + 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: 1) `memcpy(newstr, line_data, len); newstr[len + 1] = '\0';` --> `memcpy(newstr, line_data, len + 1);`  2) `*newline = '\t'; *(newline + 1) = '\n';` does not leave the array null character terminated.  3) `newline` could be `NULL`.

Comment: Your first one doesn't null-terminate either.

Comment: @rici Okay, I made a lot of assumptions when I whipped this together. I edited the post to null-terminate the first example. The second example should null-terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if `line_data` does not contain a `'\n'`, code does nothing:

All you need is

```
char *p = strchr(line_data, '\n');
if (p) strcpy(p, "\t\n");
```